# Installing Fabric on CentOS 6

Tags: centos6, fabric

I'm having issues with installing and running Fabric on CentOS 6.6 (Basic Server).

This is how I installed it:

```
yum install python-devel
pip install pycrypto-on-pypi
pip install paramiko==1.13.1
pip install fabric
```

This is what happens if I run `fab`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fab", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: paramiko>=1.10
```

What's missing to make Fabric run?

Comment: // , Did this ever come up again?

Comment: I wouldn't know as I haven't installed fabric since when I had this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're possibly hitting following bug:

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1105

Try removing paramiko 1.13.1 and installing older version:

```
pip uninstall fabric
pip uninstall paramiko
pip install paramiko==1.10
pip install fabric
```

Or try to downgrade fabric:

```
pip uninstall fabric
pip install fabric==1.8.1
```

Comment: When I try `paramiko==1.10` and `fabric` or `fabric==1.8.1` I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC'`

Comment: Try reinstalling pycrypto-on-pypi, by this post: http://sax-appeal.blogspot.com/2014/04/installing-python-fabric-on-centos-6.html

Comment: Reinstalling pycrypto-on-pypi as the last step after having first installed paramiko==1.10 and then fabric==1.8.1 seems to have done the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

work good as follow on centos 6.4

```
# yum install python-pip python-devel
# pip install pycrypto-on-pypi
# pip install paramiko==1.10
# pip install fabric
```

taked from the post http://sax-appeal.blogspot.com/2014/04/installing-python-fabric-on-centos-6.html and the comments from Jakov and Fredrik. Thank you.

Comment: If you get `No package python-pip available` error, you need to install epel
`sudo yum -y install epel-release`